# how to change color text of selected value (text, no background) in quasar q-select

Tags: vuejs3, quasar

How can I change the color of the selected value? It always stays black

It looks like this:
[image]

i have this code

```
<div>
  <q-select
            dense
            bg-color="red"
            standout="text-white"
            v-model="langModel"
            :options="options"
            option-label="LAN_NAME_HEB"
            @update:model-value = langSelected
            style="width: 110px;"
  />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.q-field__native, .q-field__prefix, .q-field__suffix, .q-field__input {
    color: red !important;
}
```

you can add this to your style - but it will change the color of every q-select. Hopefully that's what you're looking for